# Maximum overall size for all attachments

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I understand there is a limit to an attachment file size in the Crm (that can be configured), but is there a limit to the overall size of all attchments in an activity? 
Or to the num of attachments?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such limitation. The actual limit is the size of free space available for your CRM Database.